# ffmpeg VBR -> CBR conversion and streaming of MPEG-2 TS video files

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I am trying to convert a source VBR SPTS MPEG-2 TS file into CBR using ffmpeg. The code I am using is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkill ffmpeg

ffmpeg \
        -re -i source.ts -c copy \
        -muxrate 18000K \
        -f mpegts \
        udp://destination_ip:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

The source VPID bitrate is ~ 10Mbps and the APID is 296Kbps. So according to my understanding this code should deliver 18Mbps CBR where the difference between the muxrate and the bitrate of all the PIDs is filled with null packets.

The problem is that the output is far from perfect. The overall bitrate is semi-CBR at best. It ranges between 12Mbps and 15Mbps and I see a lot of PCR accuracy and PCR repetition errors along with CC errors both on the VPID and APID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

- make sure you have a recent version of `ffmpeg` because at some point there was a bug which messed up PCR insertion when stream copying
- if you want constant UDP output you must use the `bitrate` option like:

  ```
  -flush_packets 0 -f mpegts "udp://destination_ip:1234?pkt_size=1316&bitrate=18000000"
  ```
- `UDP` is an unreliable protocol and you might experience packet loss (unfortunately the `bitrate` option only works for `UDP` for now AFAIK)
- if you have a dedicated connection but still experience CC errors check the destination OS max UDP buffer sizes and make sure it can handle 18 Mbps

Comment: hmm, my ffmpeg version is 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. Tomorrow I can try to install the latest version from source. But with my current version I don't have any stuffing whatsoever and the bitrate is fluctuating largely. I have managed to achieve much better results using tsplay though. And streaming the same TS file is actually generating fewer PCR errors.

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov If you want to quickly check the latest without compiling try a recent [static build](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

Comment: @GeorgеStoyanov if you want to do true H.264 CBR instead of inserting NULL packets there's another way.

Answer (score 1):

1. specify `-minrate` and `-maxrate` too.
2. use `-bufsize` bigger than `bitrate`.
3. set `-muxrate` value like `bufsize`.

The final command:

```
ffmpeg \  
    -re -i source.ts \  
    -b:v 10500k \  
    -minrate 10500k \  
    -maxrate 10500k \  
    -bufsize 18000k \  
    -muxrate 18000k \  
    -f mpegts \  
    udp://destination_ip:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

Comment: @entrophy, thanks for your comment, I will test it and share my findings.

Comment: this command is creating something like a capped VBR with the max bitrate the configured muxrate and the video bitrate varying greatly. It is also stripping the null packets which is causing a lot of PCR errors.